# Erro tipo char C++

Tags: c++, char

Olá, estou obtendo esse erro quando tento salvar um caractere de um txt.
error: request for member ‘c_str’ in ‘d[j]’, which is of non-class type ‘char’113 |       fscanf(iFile, "%c", d[j].c_str());

Segue abaixo o trecho de código:

```
int image::paleta(string nome, int height, int width){

int i, j; 
int red,green,blue;
char d[3];
cout << "Arquivo de entrada "<< nome <<endl;
ifstream iFile(nome.c_str());

iFile.ignore(INT_MAX, '\n');

cout << width << " " << height << endl << maxcolor << endl;

for(j = 0; j<height; j++)
{
    for (i = 0; i < width; i++)
    {
        fscanf(iFile, "%c", d[j].c_str());
        if(d[0] == '.'){
            iFile >> red;
            iFile >> green;
            iFile >> blue;
            set(i,j,red,green,blue);
            cout << getred(i,j) << " " << getgreen(i,j) << " " << getblue(i,j) << " ";
        }
```

Comment: Aqui `fscanf(iFile, "%c", d[j].c_str());` você fez uma certa mistura C/C++. `char d[3];` é um array de caracteres e não uma `string` C++. Use apenas `d[j]`, supondo que `height` < 3.

Comment: não sei se entendi, não utilizo char d[3]? mas preciso guardar caracteres "." "x" ou "o"

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver utilizando

```
iFile >> dado[i];
```

para a leitura.